# Jacobian function returning error "Undefined function 'jacobian' for input arguments of type 'double'"

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use a Jacobian to solve an equation using the Newton Raphson method but I keep getting a type 'double' error. Symbolic is installed as well. I am wondering if I am using F correctly here. Do I have to use the Jacobian separately for F(1) and F(2)? Here is the script:

```
X=[0.75 0.25]; %N-dimensional array, first guess then solution
Y=[0 0];

F(1)=(X(1)^2)+(X(2)^2)-1; %right hand side functions
F(2)=X(1)+X(2)-1; %right hand side functions

MAXIT=10;
ITEST=1;
counter=0;
ABSER=0.00001;
RELER=.1;

DFDX=jacobian(F,X);

[X,ITEST,counter] =NLNR(X,F,MAXIT,counter,ABSER,RELER,ITEST,DFDX);


fprintf('answer for X1 is %d  and X2 is %d and ITEST is %d.\n',X(1),X(2),ITEST);
fprintf('number of interations is %d.\n',counter);
```

and this is the function:

```
function [X,ITEST,counter] =NLNR(X,F,MAXIT,counter,ABSER,RELER,ITEST)

while ITEST==1  %run loop as long as ITEST is 1
    counter=counter+1;  %use counter to keep track of iterations


    dX=DFDX/(-F);

    X=X+dX;


        if abs(Y(1)-X(1))<ABSER %check convergence
            ITEST=3;
        end

        if abs((Y(1)-X(1))/X(1))<RELER %check convergence
            ITEST=3;
        end

        if counter>MAXIT %check divergence
            ITEST=2;
        end

    Y(1)=X(1); %set Y to check diff in next loop
    Y(2)=X(2);        


end
```

end

Comment: I suspect you managed to name a variable `jacobian`. Check that you didn't do that, run `clear` and try again

Comment: @Amir, please don't tag `jacobian-matrix` in this question... for the love of God please.

Comment: Mhh I'm afraid the function `jacobian` requires the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/jacobian.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can easily convert your incorrect use of the symbolic `jacobian` function to use symbolic math:

```
X = [0.75 0.25];   
x = sym('x',[1 2]);
F = [x(1)^2+x(2)^2-1;
     x(1)+x(2)-1];

DFDX = jacobian(F,x)
DFDX_sub = subs(DFDX,x,X)
```

which returns

```
DFDX =

[ 2*x1, 2*x2]
[    1,    1]


DFDX_sub =

[ 3/2, 1/2]
[   1,   1]
```

Then you can use `double` to convert `DFDX_sub` to a floating point array. Note that the first argument to `jacobian` can also be a handle to a function that returns a vector (as opposed to a symbolic function or expression):

```
X = [0.75 0.25];   
x = sym('x',[1 2]);
F = @(x)[x(1)^2+x(2)^2-1;
         x(1)+x(2)-1];

DFDX = jacobian(F,x)
DFDX_sub = subs(DFDX,x,X)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no function called `jacobian` present in your matlab installation. If you read the documentation you will notice that both functions with that name are part of a toolbox:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/jacobian.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/mbc/mbccommandline/jacobian.html

Probably you don't have these toolboxes installed or licensed.

Best solution for you would probably be to search at matlab file exchange for an implementation which matches your requirements.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, I am using a school computer and it says I have symbolic installed:Symbolic Math Toolbox                                 Version 6.1        (R2014b)

Comment: @user2606257: Okay, I did not expect that error message when the symbolic toolbox is present. You have a function `jacobian` but it expects input arguments of type `sym`, not `double`. It analytically solves it, I do not know how to adapt it to your case.